# drupal 6 - count the number of menu items that are children

Tags: drupal, navigation, drupal-6, children

If my menu structure is this

- about

  - item 1
  - item 2
- work

  - item1
  - item2
  - item3
  - item 4

I want to append the menu titles in my primary nav so the show the number of menu items beneath them

```
   about (2) 
   work (4)
```

is there a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
   <?php
    function getMenuChild ($mname) {
      $arrMenu = array();
      $tree = menu_tree_all_data($mname);
      if(is_array($tree)) {
          foreach($tree as $key=>$val) {
              if(is_array($val['below']) ) {
              $arrMenu[] = $val['link']['title'].'('.count($val['below']).')' ;
          }
              else {
             $arrMenu[] = $val['link']['title'].'(0)' ;
          }
          }
      }
      return $arrMenu;
    }
    $data = getMenuChild ('primary-links');
 ?>
```